# Why does this Java code behave differently than this C code?

Tags: java, c, brainfuck

Long story how I got here; involves a Brainfuck to C compiler and a Brainfuck to JVM Bytecode compiler... seems irrelevant.
The Brainfuck code in question is as follows:

```
>-[[<+>>>-<-<+]>]
```

I've got the following C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;

void m1();
void m2();

u8 *dp;

int main() {
    dp = (u8*) calloc(30000, sizeof(u8));

    dp += 1;
    *dp -= 1;
    while(*dp) {
        m1();
    }

    return 0;
}

void m1() {
    while(*dp) {
        m2();
    }
    dp += 1;
}

void m2() {
    dp -= 1;
    *dp += 1;

    dp += 3;
    *dp -= 1;

    dp -= 1;
    *dp -= 1;

    dp -= 1;
    *dp += 1;
}
```

This code terminates.

I have this Java code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test().run();
    }

    int[] tape = new int[30000];
    int dp = 0;

    void adjust(int n) {
        tape[dp] += n;
        if(tape[dp] < 0) tape[dp] += 255;
        if(tape[dp] > 255) tape[dp] -= 255;
    }

    void run() {
        dp += 1;
        adjust(-1);
        while(tape[dp] != 0) {
            m1();
        }
    }

    void m1() {
        while(tape[dp] != 0) {
            m2();
        }
        dp += 1;
    }

    void m2() {
        dp -= 1;
        adjust(1);

        dp += 3;
        adjust(-1);

        dp -= 1;
        adjust(-1);

        dp -= 1;
        adjust(1);
    }
}
```

It does not terminate.

Why do these seemingly equivalent programs behave differently? I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  You have debuggers for both languages, USE THEM.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Hint: the C program is using function parameters (effectively local variables; passed by value) where the Java program is using an instance variable (a field).

Comment: Did you try to debug it step-wise? You could even do this side by side and watch exactly when it starts to differ.

Comment: @ruakh Sorry, that is true, I just corrected it by just making 'dp' a global, and the behavior is the same. I'll update the post.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code to see where they do something different should find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These codes are not equal:

1. C version allocates byte array where as Java's - integer array
2. C version does not do clamping of array elements as Java does

So in Java you should make a byte array instead:

```
byte[] tape = new byte[30000];
```

And remove clamping in adjust() function:

```
 // if(tape[dp] < 0) tape[dp] += 255;
 // if(tape[dp] > 255) tape[dp] -= 255;
```

Then Java's version terminates too

**OR** if you want to keep *integer* array - then you must change your overflow/underflow rules :

```
 if(tape[dp] < 0) tape[dp] = 256-Math.abs(tape[dp]) % 256;
 if(tape[dp] > 255) tape[dp] = tape[dp] % 256;
```

because you implemented them not right

Comment: This confuses me because in the C version I was using unsigned 8-bit (on my platform & compiler) integers; 0-255. I was attempting to emulate this in Java by using 32-bit integers and implementing the wrapping functionality myself.
I tested the C code to verify that it does wrap (i.e. 255+1 == 0 and 0-1==255)
So I don't understand why they don't behave identically.

Comment: See my answer edit. Yes, indeed C does perform underflow/overflow, but you implemented them _incorrectly_